# Angular 6 - Accessing variable outside function not working

Tags: angular

```
export class EditClientComponent implements OnInit {

 apiEndPoint: 'http://localhost:1337/upload';

 fileChange(event) {
 //...
    this.http.post(`${this.apiEndPoint}`, formData, httpOptions)
 //...
 }
}
```

I get a weird error:

`status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:4100/undefined"...`

Which means that it's not reading `apiEndPoint` **at all**, and if I replace `${this.apiEndPoint}` with the actual url, it works.

What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change the declaration of apiEndPoint to **=** instead of **:**

```
apiEndPoint = 'http://localhost:1337/upload';
```

you are specifying the type of the variable not an initial value.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above reply. You don't need to format a string if you already have the full value of the URL in the var. Instead of this: `${this.apiEndPoint}`. Simply do:

```
this.http.post(this.apiEndPoint, formData, httpOptions)
```

Answer (score 1):

In here `apiEndPoint: 'http://localhost:1337/upload';` is statement of declare the type of `apiEndPoint` to string literal and it is initial value is `undefined`.

Just fixed to this

```
apiEndPoint:string = 'http://localhost:1337/upload';
```